# Ionic 4 Navigation, not able to navigate to pages directly after deploying to azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ionic4

I am working on a Ionic app with multiple pages, the navigation works fine when I navigate by clicking on links in the app.

For example, in the left menu, when I click on Settings, its going to www.azuresite.com/settings and its displaying everything fine

[image]

But when I copy and try to visit the same url in new tab, I get the below error message

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This issue is not occurring when I am trying in localhost after Ionic Serve and it happens only after I paste everything from www folder to Azure app

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding the below web.config file in azure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```